# Is subtraction a binary operation on $S$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

According to what I have been instructed before seeing this question, am suppose to subtract these number until I obtain a set of numbers that are non-negative and all less than 6.I am trying to determine whether subtraction is a binary operation on $S=\{2,4,5,6\}$. How best can I undersand how to answer such a question. In matrix form the rows of the solution are as follows: $R1= 0 2 3 4$, $R2=-2 0 1 2$, $R3=-3 -1 0 1$ and $R4=-4 -2 -1 0$. Accordinding to what I was taught, this subtraction is not a binary operation because the result has negative numbers in it despite all outcomes are less than 6.

Comment: Subtraction is not a binary operation on $S=\{2,4,5,6\}$ BUT the bit about "numbers that are non-negative and all less than 6" suggests that maybe you are supposed to work with residues modulo 6. Well, even if that's the case, subtraction is not a binary operation on $S$ because 5 and 4 are in $S$ but $5-4=1$ isn't. Still, it would help if you could write out the complete instructions, as they were given to you.

Comment: I agree with Gerry. Addition and multiplication are not operations on the set, in their standard definitions.